# How to interpret asterisks in a tracert command. Does this sugest an issue?

Tags: windows, networking, traceroute

we have a 3rd party application installed on our application server, "myservername." The 3rd part company tells us that the application is very chatty and quickly performs poorly unless there is are very good network speeds.

I am concerned about the asterisks that I am seeing when I do a tracert command to the application server. Does this suggest an issue with the app server? As I understand it, the asterisks means that the last hop to the app server took longer than expected. because there are two asterisks, did it involve a retry also?

Does this suggest a problem? Some VDI users talking to the app server get horrible performance.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1667]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Y:>tracert myservername

Tracing route to myservername.internal.mycompany.com [1.2.3.4]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  6.7.8.9
  2     1 ms     2 ms     1 ms  cd-sc-2b-po-21.inw.mycompany.com [2.3.4.5]
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  cd-dcaz-1a-po23.inw.mycompany.com [3.4.5.6]
  4     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  cd-dcaz-ce-3a-po5.inw.mycompany.com [5.6.7.8]
  5    10 ms    10 ms    10 ms  adc-dcaz-ce-1a-et1-1.inw.mycompany.com [9,10,11,12]
  6    10 ms     9 ms     9 ms  adc-sc-1b-et1-1.inw.mycompany.com [13.14.15.16]
  7    10 ms     9 ms    10 ms  adc-f1-ecaz-1a-et1-56.inw.mycompany.com [17.18.19.20]
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10    12 ms    20 ms    17 ms  myservername.internal.mycompany.com [1.2.3.4]

Trace complete.

Y:\>tracert myservername

Tracing route to myservername.internal.mycompany.com [1.2.3.4]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  6.7.8.9
  2     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  cd-sc-2b-po-21.inw.mycompany.com [2.3.4.5]
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  cd-dcaz-1a-po23.inw.mycompany.com [3.4.5.6]
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  cd-dcaz-ce-3a-po5.inw.mycompany.com [5.6.7.8]
  5    17 ms    13 ms    10 ms  hry-dcaz-ce-1a-et1-1.inw.mycompany.com [9,10,11,12]
  6     9 ms     9 ms     9 ms  hry-sc-1b-et1-1.inw.mycompany.com [13.14.15.16]
  7     9 ms    10 ms     9 ms  hry-f1-ecaz-1a-et1-56.inw.mycompany.com [17.18.19.20]
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10    11 ms    10 ms    10 ms  myservername.internal.mycompany.com [1.2.3.4]

Trace complete.

Y:\>
```

Comment: Traceroute uses icmp. Alot of networking equipment drops icmp packets if the packet is destined for them or has a hop count that means the packet terminates on them.
This does not mean there is a problem in and of itself.
Remember switches and routers are there to pass packets, not to respond to them